# Rotate CustomView without affecting the activity

Tags: android, android-custom-view

[image]
[image]

Hi I have a floating window in which my floating window serves as the video and it also have a controls inside the video which under the floating window

Now my question is it possible that I can rotate my custom view from floating window only without affecting the orientation of my activity

If someone already tried it please guide me towards it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never done it before. But I have an idea. You can use the below code to get the current orientation of the screen on your device.

```
OrientationEventListener onrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int rotation) {
                Logger.e("Orientation: " + rotation);
            }
        };
```

And after that, depends on the value of "rotation", you can use rotate animation in Android to rotate your custom view.

@Beginer: Here is the code I implemented it. I used the above code in my custom view in my small camera app. It helps me to know which degree should I rotate the bitmap after taken. The `toScreenOrientation()` method bellow return a value in degrees (0, 90, 180, 270) **you also modify it by yourself(whatever you want)**.

Using `setOrientationChangedListener()` method to help the parent(Activity, Fragment,  etc.) receives a callback also.

```
public class TakePhotoView extends ConstraintLayout {

    private static final int SCREEN_ORIENTATION_0 = 0;
    private static final int SCREEN_ORIENTATION_90 = 90;
    private static final int SCREEN_ORIENTATION_180 = 180;
    private static final int SCREEN_ORIENTATION_270 = 270;

    private OnOrientationChangedListener mOnOrientationChangedListener;

    private OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener;

    private int mScreenRotation;

    public TakePhotoView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TakePhotoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        //....do something here

        mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int rotation) {
                Logger.e("Orientation: " + rotation);

                if (rotation == OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
                    mScreenRotation = DEFAULT_SCREEN_ROTATION;
                    return;
                }

                mScreenRotation = rotation;

                if(mOnOrientationChangedListener != null){
                    mOnOrientationChangedListener.onOrientationChanged(rotation);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void takePhoto(Camera camera) {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
        }
    }

    private Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            final int screenRotation = mScreenRotation;

            int rotate = toScreenOrientation(screenRotation);

            // Rotate/Flip the bitmap depends on the 'rotate' value
        }
    };

    /**
     * Converts sensor rotation in degrees to screen orientation constants.
     *
     * @param rotation sensor rotation angle in degrees
     * @return Screen orientation angle in degrees (0, 90, 180, 270).
     */
    private int toScreenOrientation(int rotation) {
        if (rotation > 290 || rotation <= 70) {
            return SCREEN_ORIENTATION_0;
        } else if (rotation > 70 && rotation <= 110) {
            return SCREEN_ORIENTATION_90;
        } else if (rotation > 110 && rotation <= 250) {
            return SCREEN_ORIENTATION_180;
        } else {
            return SCREEN_ORIENTATION_270;
        }
    }

    public void setOrientationChangedListener(OnOrientationChangedListener orientationChangedListener){
        this.mOnOrientationChangedListener = orientationChangedListener;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Interfaces
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public interface OnOrientationChangedListener {
        void onOrientationChanged(int rotation);
    }
}
```

**Can I use this listener even I disable rotation in my manifest?**
-> It still works fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi sir thank you for the feed back , Now my question is can I use this handler or listener in custom view alone? 
if yes how can I implements it.
also can I use this listener even I disable rotation in my manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not want your Activity to be recreated on device rotation.
If so, then add *configChanges* attribute in AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
      ...
      android:configChanges="orientation" >
```

This will stop activity recreation on rotation. But in your activity you can check that device has been rotated in onConfigurationChanged() method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  // Checks the orientation of the screen
  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    ...
  } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    ...
  }
}
```

Do not forget to read [android developer guides.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) ;)

Comment: Hi sir.
I also already use this approach and already know this
but in this scenario I just wanted to rotate the customview alone

Comment: @Beginner, what view do you use for video rendering? What View does your custom view extend?

Comment: RelativeLayout sir

Comment: @Beginner, sir, i do not clearly understand you. RelativeLayout is ViewGroup. It is like container for other view which will be used for video rendering. What view do you use for video rendering?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this but I used alertDailog. The logic will be the same for all views.

```
AlertDialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stack_overflow2);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    AlertDialog.Builder alert123 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StackOverflow2.this);
    View current_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.password_alert,null);
    l2 = current_view.findViewById(R.id.linearView);
    // Here l2 is linear layout getting root layout of password_alert

    alert123.setView(current_view);
    dialog = alert123.create();
    dialog.show();

    OrientationEventListener onrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(getBaseContext(), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int rotation) {
            Log.e("Orientation: " , String.valueOf(rotation));

            if(rotation==270 || rotation==90)
            {
                if(rotation==270)
                {
                    l2.setRotation(90);
                }
                else
                {
                    l2.setRotation(270);
                }
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                Toast.makeText(StackOverflow2.this, "Change Dialog Rotation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                if(rotation==180)
                {
                    l2.setRotation(180);
                }
                else
                {
                    l2.setRotation(0);
                }

                Toast.makeText(StackOverflow2.this, "Normal Display to Occur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    };
    if (onrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        Log.v("ORIE", "Can detect orientation");
        onrientationEventListener.enable();
    } else {
        Log.v("ORIE", "Cannot detect orientation");
        onrientationEventListener.disable();
    }

}
```

Here are some pictures : 
0 Degree

[image: 0 Degree]

90 Degree

[image: 90 Degree]

270 Degree

[image: 270 Degree]

As you can see the background activity is in potrait mode always. The alert dialog's height and width is a little off but you can change your view's dimensions differently. I hope this code solves your problem.